# Problem with Office 2007 MIME Types, they download as *.zip in IE all other Browsers ok

Tags: tomcat, apache2, mime, office-2007

We have a custom CMS running on Tomcat, we added the following config:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet .xlsx
```

I can download those Excel 2007 Files without Problems in FF, OP, Chrome, Safari. But in IE I get a Download Box for a ZIP File. I changed IE8 Settings to recognize Filetypes from Fileextension, after that IE8 displays the File as plain text.

Problem, one of our bigger customers are restricted to only use IE, so at the moment the only solution for them is to zip the files before they upload them and unzip them after download. But that is not a real solution.

Anybody here with a solution for me?

We are using Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to confirm that the Content-Type header is being sent to the browser. If it is not, then make sure the mime type listed in the question is properly listed in web.xml. Also confirm the file is being served by Tomcat and not apache - which can be verified by checking the access logs on bother servers after the browser makes the request.

Answer (score 0):

Similar tests work fine for me when I explicitly type

response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

in my servlet.... Also Fiddler as suggested by Tim or WireShark might be very useful to see what's being served